# ¿Cual es el tamaño máximo de una imagen que puede soportar base64?

Tags: archivo, base64, fileupload

Estoy tratando de decidirme por una forma para enviar imagenes a mi base de datos, y estaba pensando en mandarlas en base64 pero mayormente mis imagenes pueden pesar más de 5MB ya que son de alta resolución.
Tendría problemas al usar base64?
De que otra forma podria?

Comment: Porque querrias enviar las imagenes a tu base de datos, cuando el sistema operativo se ocupa de ellas de lo mas bien? mas alla de eso, base64 es una forma de codificar para que ningun byte sea mayor a 64... entonces a que te referis con tamaño?

Comment: Yo las guardaría en forma de fichero y en la BBDD la ruta.
El límite, probablemente lo pone la BBDD.

Comment: Las imágenes (o cualquier dato) codificadas en [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) tienden a aumentar su tamaño (espacio en bytes) hasta un [33%](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#Encoded_size_increase). Por lo tanto, no solo es ineficiente sino que añades una sobrecarga adicional, tanto en el uso de ancho de banda, como de espacio de almacenamiento. Usa Base64 sólo cuando la comunicación entre pares requiera el uso estricto de caracteres ASCII. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo, perdonen si estoy bastante perdido en este tema pero es primer vez que me topo con ello.

Comment: @Alfabravo base64 no es un hash. Por definición, de un hash no puedes ir de vuelta al dato original, es un algoritmo de _una vía_, y base64 es de dos vías (es la idea, codificas en base64 con la intención de algún día volver al original), pues es un algoritmo que surgió de la necesidad de transportar datos binarios por protocolos que solo soportaban transportar texto.

Comment: @gbianchi hay casos donde puedes querer almacenar imágenes en una DB por razones prácticas. Si bien el sistema operativo las maneja de lo más bien, hay bases de datos también las manejan de lo más bien. ;)

Comment: @jachguate nunca dije lo contrario.. solo dije que el SO suele ocuparse muy bien de eso.. sobre todo cuando son imagenes grandes.. y no hay que transformarlas ;)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo en eso ;)

Comment: Bueno, pensándolo bien, dependiendo del caso de uso, yo a veces las comprimo, a menos que el formato en el que están ya tenga compresión, se puede ganar espacio, a cambio de un poco de tiempo de procesador. Como siempre, suele no haber respuestas absolutas, siempre depende... como dijo Pepito. ;)

Comment: Muy cierto, @jachguate. Procedo a eliminar las mentiras de estos comentarios :)

Answer (score 3):

Base 64 es una forma de representar valores binarios en cadenas de caracteres, por definición no tiene limite de datos. Como lo dicen los comentarios el límite depende de la base de datos, pero comprendo la limitante de algunos motores o de una infraestructura ya existente.

Mi sugerencia es la siguiente:

```
int tamaño_bloque = 10*1024;

string b64Text = ConvertirArchivoBinario(FileReader("mi-ruta.txt"));

string []segmentos = PartirArchivosEnSegmentos(b64Text,tamaño_bloque);
```

y guardas con un reespectivo orden los sub-base-64 contenidos en segmentos.

ConvertirArchivoBinario :
Esto varía según el lenguaje:
c#

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

PartirArchivosEnSegmentos : Se debe implementar bajo tu propio criterio.

Pros:

- Puedes guardar cualquier archivo en forma de string.
- No vas a tener problema con los acentos ( Sí estas guardando string en base 64
  que he visto que lo hacen para "cifrar" datos es un alivio con los acentos).
- Puedes implementar un FUSE (FileSystem Virtual) en un servidor de correo, o en una base de datos :)

Contras:

- Requiere gasto computacional de procesador.
- Requiere gasto computacional de memoria.
- Toma más espacio almacenarlas.
- No tienes un control de acls ( lectura/escritura/permisos ) y mucho menos puede ser leído por un AntiVirus
- Si quieres comprimirlo la tasa de compresión es muy pobre.

Conclusión:

Debes evaluar esta situación y evaluar costo beneficio con un benchmark.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Base64 es básicamente una forma de representar datos binarios (es decir, cualquier cosa) utilizando solamente *caracteres imprimibles* del código ASCII (es decir, texto *legible*, que tiene básicamente solo letras, números y algunos símbolos de uso común).

Para responder tu pregunta entonces:

Como tal no tiene ningún límite de tamaño *per se*.  Los límites están generalmente impuestos por el hardware y software que se utilice para procesarlo.

### Base 64 puede *soportar* una imagen (o archivo) de cualquier tamaño

Siempre que tu infraestructura (hardware y software) pueda manejar el *archivo* resultante, que va a ser de mayor tamaño a la imagen.

Esto, porque, por definición tu puedes convertir un *archivo* de cualquier tamaño a su representación en Base64, que simplemente te dará un archivo más grande.

El archivo será más grande porque cada 6 bits del archivo de entrada tomarán un byte completo del archivo de salida. En otras palabras, por cada 3 bytes del archivo de entrada se ocupará 4 bytes en el archivo de salida.

Si el tamaño de tu archivo de entrada en bytes, no es múltiplo de 3, se agregará algunos bytes adicionales a la salida, cuyo tamaño siempre será múltiplo de 4.

En otras palabras, si tu codificas un archivo de 5MB, que son 5 242 880 bytes, esto producirá una salida de `redondear.arriba(5242880/3) * 4`, es decir 6 990 508 bytes o 6.66MB.

Si tu infraestructura (lenguaje de programación, servidor web, base de datos, sistema operativo, memoria, disco duro, sistema de archivos, etc) soporta manejar 6.66MB, entonces no tendrás problema en manejar archivos de 5MB codificados en base64.

Como dato curioso, agregar que incluso puedes convertir un archivo de texto (que puede ya estar en base64) a base64. El algoritmo de conversión no se fija en el contenido de la entrada, simplemente va convirtiendo cada 3 bytes de entrada en 4 caracteres imprimibles en la salida, donde cada caracter ocupa un byte.

Por ejemplo, la secuencia binaria de bytes (representados en hexadecimal) `00 FF AA`, se representará en base64 como la cadena `'AP+q'`

La cadena `'Hola mundo'` (en ASCII o en UTF8), quedará codificada en la cadena `'aG9sYSBtdW5kbw=='`

En ese último caso, la cadena de entrada tiene 10 bytes (que no es múltiplo de 3), puedes observar como la cadena de salida tiene 16, que si es múltiplo de 4. Cualquier entrada con entre 10, 11 y 12 bytes, producirá una salida de 16.

Comment: Gracias por la información me fue muy útil

Answer (score 0):

Antes de que comiences a con lo de convertir imagenes a base de datos, tenes que configurar un poquitin tu DB

En mi caso utilizo MySQL, encima de la columna donde estaria la imagen por ejemplo esta una de mis columnas:

```
@Column(name = "fotoLibro", columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
private String fotoLibro;
```

Poruqe si solamente pones que sea un string, no dara abasto para todo el Base64, usando ese @Column estas dandole la dificion de LONGTEXT a esa columna y si podra guardar todo el Base64 (Al menos de esta forma me funciona a mi).

Te dejo el codigo que utilice para poder hacer la conversion con ANGULAR:

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="publicar()" novalidate #f="ngForm">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <label for="image-libro"></label>
                    <input 
                    [(ngModel)]="publicacion.fotoLibro"
                    name="image-libro"
                    (change)="capturarImagen($event)"
                    type="file" 
                    alife-file-to-base64  
                    id="image-libro" 
                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg" 
                    >
                </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
    public imagenbase64: string;

    capturarImagen(event: any) {
    const imagenCapturada = event.target.files[0];
    this.extraerBase64(imagenCapturada).then((imagen: any) => {
      this.imagenbase64 = imagen.base;
    });
   }

   extraerBase64 = async ($event: any) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const unsafeImg = window.URL.createObjectURL($event);
        const image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImg);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL($event);
        reader.onload = () => {
          resolve({
            base: reader.result,
          });
        };
        reader.onerror = (error) => {
          resolve({
            base: null,
          });
        };
      } catch (e) {}
    });
```

Ahora bien, con la funcion extraerBase64 convertis la imagen en formato base64, y con la funcion capturarImagen la cual la implementas en el input,es para que al elegir la imaegn desde el input, corra esta funcion, acapture el archivo, llame a la funcion extrarBase64 y conviereta la imagen a Base64.

Te preguntaras, como hago el envio de ese string base64 a mi DB? te dejo como ejemplo como lo implemente yo usando FormData;

En mi formulario veras que en la etiqueta form, tiene un `(ngSubmit)="publicar()"` , te adjunto la funcion:

**TypeScript**

```
publicar(): void {
    const formData = {
      titulo: this.publicacion.titulo,

      **fotoLibro: this.imagenBase64,**

      autor: this.publicacion.autor,

      anoPublicacion: this.publicacion.anoPublicacion,

      editorial: this.publicacion.editorial,

      genero: this.publicacion.genero,

      numPaginas: this.publicacion.numPaginas,

      sinopsis: this.publicacion.sinopsis,

      resenia: this.publicacion.resenia,
    };
    this.publicacionService.crearPublicacion(formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        
        )
        this.router.navigate(['/publicaciones']);
      },
      (err) => {
        alert("Error al publicar");
      }
    );
  }
```

Debes inicializar cada parte de tu modelo en el FormData, pero en donde debes inicializar la imagen, llamas al String imagenBase64, ya que ahi se estara alojando tu imagen en Base64, luego del formData, haces el llamado de tu Service, en mi caso es: `this.publicacionService.crearPublicacion(formData).subscribe();`

Aunque el tema del service depende como lo tengas hecho, en mi casi solo pide 1 argumento.
este seria mi peticion post:

```
public crearPublicacion(publicacion: Publicacion){
    return this.http.post<Publicacion>(`${this.ApiPublicacion}nuevo`, publicacion);
  }
```

Ya si aplicas bien esta informacion, no deberias tener problemas.